# Vertically center an icon and text inside a div

Tags: css

I want to center an image and its title inside a div with this css code

```
.box {border:2px solid #0094ff;}
.title {background-color:pink;color:white;height:10px; line-height:3px; padding:10px;}
.content {color:#333;padding:10px;}
.box {
    -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
}

.titleIkon{
margin-right:2%;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

By the look of this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7kx4r/ i can tell that nor the icon or the text is centered.How do i fix this?.

Comment: Remove unnecessary CSS and use the CSS as given in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12107570/1516616) below;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove unnecessary CSS and use the following CSS:

```
.title {background-color:pink;color:white; padding:10px; }
.titleIkon{
    margin-right:2%;
    display:inline;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/QX44R/)

Comment: its easy and traditional method of vertical alignment but as OP asked the question we are trying to giving the answer according to that without padding :-)

Comment: I didn't added any css rule in existing css rules as OP stated above. I've just removed unnecessary CSS rules declaration. And OP didn't mentioned that he don't want solution without use of `padding`.

Comment: @flapjack So true - Padding top and bottom is something used to ADJUST the elements vertically middle. As OP used display: teble-cell; we were thinking about logical answer..... :)

Comment: ya exactly Dipak now days we mostly use this method and as per OP's coding we answered anyways gud people needs solution here so its depends on the requirement what he needs :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `.title` class `display: table-cell;`

```
.title{
  margin-right:2%;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kx4r/16/)

Note: Table-cell doesn't work in Old IE browsers

Comment: @flapjack Updated fiddle - you need to specify width in PX

Comment: read more about display:table and display:table-cell :- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 0):

use `text-align` with your `div` having class `title` as

```
text-align: center;
```

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7kx4r/4/

Answer (score 0):

something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/7kx4r/8/

just add `width:XXXpx; margin:0 auto;`

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this CSS:

```
.box {border:2px solid #0094ff;}
.title {background-color:pink;color:white;height:10px; line-height:3px; padding:10px;}
.content {color:#333;padding:10px;}
.box {
    position:relative;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
}

.titleIkon{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
```

What's going on here:
position:relative creates a new offset context for .box's children.

position:absolute tells .titleIkon to use offset parameters (left, right, top, bottom) relative to .box

top:50% tells .titleIkon that it should consider it's top edge position to be 50% of the height of the parent.

margin-top: -8px tells the browser to move the image up by half it's height (16px / 2 = 8px)

Answer (score 0):

just define `display:table-cell;` `vertical-align:middle;` to your **.title** class.

[its work IE8 to IE 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell)

see the dmeo - http://jsfiddle.net/7kx4r/10/

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want this.

give `text-align: center` if you want only the pink line to be in center.http://jsfiddle.net/7kx4r/17/